# Can't save my Photoshop work as a .png anymore

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, save

Recently I made an Windows update on my computer, but since the update I can't save my projects as a .png anymore.

This is a major problem for me, because I'm building up the website for our company and I need pictures with transparent backgrounds.

Is this problem relating to the Windows update I've made and why didn't it occur before?

[image: Screenshot showing no PNG option given]

Comment: What was the windows update? There are many and there is not telling which one you made (or for which Win version, looks like 7). I reccomend using Save for web over Save As. It gives you insights into image optimisations. (Ctrl + Shift + Alt + s)

Comment: Saw this on Adobe Forum... maybe check if you have this (png.8bi): C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS3\Plug-Ins\File Formats\Png.8bi. On the same forum post, the issue of the OP was not scrolling down 2 files after RAW; PNG should be there.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your colour profile is set to RGB, you cannot save a CMYK doc as a .png file and therefore will not get the option in your dropdown menu when saving. (Click Image > Mode to do this)

You may have made a document with a bit/channel in excess of 16bit png will not support this. See [this site](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/) for more details on png specifications.

...There is also the File > Save for Web option! ;)

(In newer versions of Photoshop CC though the function to save for web is still there, the navigation has changed however the keyboard shortcuts are still as follows: ctrl + alt + shift + s (win) or cmd + opt + shift + s (Mac))

Hope this helps!

Comment: You're 100% right and this answer might be useful, but I notice his screenshot shows RGB/8bits. I'm wondering what could be the issue, your solution seems to be the most logical answer to this problem!

Comment: Woopsies, didn't notice  the details in the screenshot, sort of jumped the gun on what the problem might be. I would imagine that savefor web should be a work around then and scrolling may very well be the solution! :)